# Cannot convert from type1 to type1 in netstandard error

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I've been lured into creating NetStandard libraries in 2017RC. I have come across 2 bizarre errors

> - Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UtilityLibrary.CountryHelpers.Country.CountryCode
>     [...UtilityLibrary\Country\Country.cs(10)]' to
>     'UtilityLibrary.CountryHelpers.Country.CountryCode [Common,
>     Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]'
> - Error   CS0433  The type 'Regex' exists in both 'System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System, Version=4.0.0.0,
>     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

After doing some searching, these are the things I've tried:

- a clean of the entire solution and build
- removing each project and re-adding them, setting the references after readding them

Why am I seeing the regex error? I literally just created a few libraries in one sitting!

Comment: Any target framework version difference?

Comment: The Regex one is a conflict between the System and System.Text.RegularExpressions references. One of them has to go.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Nope, all Netstandard 1.4.

Comment: @PaulStelian where do I find the references to remove one?

Comment: The references can be found by right clicking the individual project. From there I can't really remember (more than a year since I last used VS) but you should be able to find it.